# Unable to access chronograf UI running on EC2 instance port 8888 in a docker container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, chronograf

I started Chronograf on an EC2 instance on port 8888. My EC2 instance is running Ubuntu. When I ssh into the instance and do

> curl <my_ec2_public_DNS>:8888

I get a valid response.

Now when I try to go the URL http://<my_ec2_public_DNS>:8888 from a browser on my computer, my request always times out. I am able to `ping <my_ec2_public_DNS>` from my computer.

My EC2 security inbound rules are as follows:

[image]

Please help.

Edit 1: I am running chronograf in a docker container.

```
chronograf:
    image: chronograf:latest
    volumes:
      - ./my_dir/data/:/var/lib/chronograf/
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    depends_on:
      - influxdb
```

Comment: When you do `netstat -tlpn` on that instance, what you can see for the 8888 port? If the docker process is not attached to your ENI, you need to NAT to it and also allow ip_forward.

Comment: I did ss -tlpn | grep 8888 and this is what I see: ```LISTEN 0      4096         0.0.0.0:8888       0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN 0      4096            [::]:8888          [::]:*```